# How to create KM curves and Cox PH model with time-dependent covariate

Tags: sas, survival-analysis, cox-regression

Some patient received an treatment as treated group and some did not as control group. In order to consider **"immortal time bias"**, I coded the treatment as a time-dependent covariate. **Could you let me know it is right or not?** Thanks.
For example, there are two patients:
P1 received the treatment 30 days after the start of this study and died 30 days after receiving the treatment.
P2 did not received the treatment and survived at the end of this study (80 days).
Here I code the data as follow:

```
ID  Treatment   Time    Death
P1  0   30  0
P1  1   30  1
P2  0   80  0
```

Then I just used SAS code to create KM curves

```
/*Survival curve*/
proc lifetest data=treatment;
time Time*Dearg(0);
strata Treatment;
run;
```

and run Cox PH model

```
/*Cox PH Model*/
proc phreg data=treatment;
model Time*Death(0)=treatment;
run;
```

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: It is my question. I am not sure what I did is right or not. Thanks

Comment: Gotcha, thank you! This would best be asked on cross-validated. Stackoverflow is more for SAS programming questions, such as how you would actually program this model in SAS.